# WORDTABLE - Not matching the word - UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

I've tried to match a word using **WORDTABLE**. But some text is not matching.

In the below input the word Afghanistan is not matching. If I remove **A Coruña;n.a.** from WORDTABLE, then it's matching.

**Sample Input:**

```
Afghanistan
Report
report
```

**Sample CSV ( test.csv):**

```
Afghanistan;Afghan.
report;rep.
A Coruña;n.a.
```

**Code:**

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;
RETAINTYPE(SPACE);
WORDTABLE Table = 'test.csv';
DECLARE Annotation Abbr(STRING short);
Document{->MARKTABLE(Abbr, 1, Table,true,0,"",0, "short" = 2)};   
RETAINTYPE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the whitespace in the wordlist. There are several options to avoid this problem, e.g., activating the configuration parameter [dictRemoveWS](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.basic.parameter.dictRemoveWS).

Comment: There is also [UIMA-6092](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/UIMA-6092) for avoiding this common problem.